# plotly hoverlabel color transparency

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

Is it possible to format `hoverlabel` so that the background color is transparent & it's possible to see the plot through the labels?

I can set it to a solid color by e.g. `hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = '#fff')` but looks like if I try to add transparency, that part of the color string gets ignored. Same with `bgcolor = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.05)'`, doesn't work either. Looks like for markers there is `opacity` setting, but not for hoverlabels.

Thanks!!

Comment: Currently setting the opacity for a hoverlabel isn't possible. `hoverlabel.opacity` is part of an [open issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/2342) regarding plotly.js

Comment: I see, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found (in plotly python), that if you pass `hovermode = "x unified"` in `layout`, then if you set `bgcolor` to some `rgba` value that includes transparency, it does work! I am not aware of the R code for that but it should be easy to figure out. Here's what it looks like (pretty sick imo!) -

[image]

Here's the (python) code-

```
fig.update_layout(hovermode='x unified', legend=dict(title= None), hoverlabel=dict(bgcolor='rgba(255,255,255,0.75)',
                                                                                  font=dict(color='black')))
```

Comment: Thanks! In R this would be `layout(fig, hovermode = 'x unified', hoverlabel=list(bgcolor='rgba(255,255,255,0.75)', font=list(color='black')))`.

Comment: @laxxy Did you try it in R? Does it apply transparency?

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is using CSS selector with css file in `www` folder and included the css in `ui.R` file like this

This approach allow you to have color variable set for each label compare to hard code in the accepted answer.

```r
 dashboardBody(
   # use the css to set opacity of hover label - here I use tag$head in shinydashboard
   tags$head(
     tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "styles.css")
   )
   # more code here ...
)
```

```css
# this file located in www/styles.css
g.hovertext > path {
  opacity: .6;
}
```

This approach will result that every hover text on the page got the opacity setting not one specific plot. For specific plot it would require some extra work on the selector.
[image]

---

**Edit:** a reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(HTML("g.hovertext > path {opacity: .6;}")),
  plotlyOutput("myPlot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$myPlot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, type = "scatter", mode = "lines")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Good solution! This however doesn't modify the plotly object - it's working in a `shiny` context.